# Jmeter - convert a string to base64

Tags: jmeter

I've just started out trying to write some tests in jmeter. It's the first time I've used it in earnest, and I'm struggling a bit with it.

I am running a test that searches for data on a website.

The returned data is in the format baseURL/customerID=

Now, the customer number depends on the customer being searched for and it is in base64.

I'm struggling to see how I can get the url updated.

I can see in the request that the field is parameter, and I know what the value is, as I have it stored in a csv file as CustomerID.

How can I convert that csv data to the url parameter?

I'm trying to use beanshell at the moment with this:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String customerID = vars.get("customerID");
String customerStringEncoded = Bas64Encoder.encode(customerID);
vars.put("customerStringEncoded",customerStringEncoded);
```

But it seems that it can't locate customerID.

I am supplying it wiht ${CustomerID} in the preprossor menu option, but I don't know what is wrong.

the error is "Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: encode() on undefined variable or class name: Bas64Encoder
"

Any tips?

Thanks

tgb

Answer (score 0):

If the data is being stored in csv, you can use the "**CSV Data Set config**" to read the CSV File. CSVhttp://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for responding. I am reading my data from the CSV data set config. Within that file I also have names and other search criteria.

The data in the csv file is stored in a text format, but I want to convert it to base64 for the URL. I could do this in the file beforehand, but it would mean changing that data every time I update that file. 

I want change the format in jmeter. I think I'm close with this piece of code: 

`vars.put("CustomerID", new String(Base64.EncodeBase64($CustomerID}))); ` but I'm having trouble converting it back into a variable to use

Comment: This is the current error I am encountering:`Encountered "( \"CustomerID\" , new String ( Base64 . EncodeBase64 ( $CustomerID }"`

Comment: I seem to be getting closer. I'm currently trying this `int num = vars.get(${CustomerID});` However, it seems that you can't use vars.get with an int. Anyone know how to convert it?

Comment: You can use Integer.parseInt(vars.get("")) to convert into an integer